# BotFramework ReceiptCard not displayed on Skype Desktop

Tags: botframework

I created a small bot with the microsoft botFramework Recepit card like described in [this article](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html)

The receipt item is defined like this:
The Cardaction is defined like this

```
  CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
            {
                Value = connection.VendorLink,
                Type = "openUrl",
                Title = "To Vendor"
            };
```

the receipt like ths:

```
  ReceiptItem lineItem1 = new ReceiptItem()
            {
                Title = titel,
                Subtitle = subtitel,
                Text = null,
                Image = new CardImage(url: connection.CompanyLogo),
                Price = connection.Price.ToString() + " EUR",
                Quantity = "1",
                Tap = null
            };
```

On skype on my smartphone everythig looks cool

[image]

but when I use it in skype desktop it looks like this:

[image]

and when I click it i'm redirected to the skype download page : https://www.skype.com/de/download-skype/skype-for-computer/?nonce=rTYEWMbCE2PuIzo4qO8B

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that my skype on desktop was not the most current version